# How to sort list of locale objects in list interface using comparator in java

Tags: java

I would like to sort Locale objects in list interface.
below is the code i am using.
`List<Locale> list = LocaleUtils.availableLocaleList();
LocaleUtils.availableLocaleList()` on calling this we are getting the list of available locales in java, `localeutils` is the class from `org.apache.commons.lang.LocaleUtils`.

I am trying to using the comparator interface below code.

```
            List<Locale> locale = LocaleUtils.availableLocaleList();
    Comparator<Locale> comparator = new Comparator<Locale>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Locale o1, Locale o2) {
            return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    System.out.println(list);
```

I am able to print all the locales before sorting. But I am not able to sort the locale objects I am getting the below exception.

Could you  please help me to sort it this issue.

any body could you please help me.
Thanks and Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 4):

You are using an unmodifiable list. If you put the elements in a modifiable list it can be sorted. Otherwise you could your own sorting algorithm that put the elements in a new list. This approach could be faster. 
Try this instead:

```
List<Locale> localeList = new ArrayList<Locale>(list);
Collections.sort(localeList, comparator);
```